# has_term or in_category for Custom Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

I have `property` as a custom post type. I want to display a specific message if the property is in the `sold` category. To do that, I'm using the function below:

```
if ( has_term('sold', 'category')) {
  ?>
  <div class="sold_prop_note">
    <h3>This Property is sold. Take a look at our current exclusives! <a href="/properties">View Exclusives</a></h3>
  </div>
  <?
}
```

Before using the above, I also tried in_category like the one below:

```
if ( in_category( array( 'sold', 'homepage-sold' ) )) {
  ?>
  <div class="sold_prop_note">
    <h3>This Property is sold. Take a look at our current exclusives! <a href="/properties">View Exclusives</a></h3>
  </div>
  <?
}
```

Both of the haven't worked. To add the Custom Post Type, the taxonomies were with `'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag' )`.

Both are being used inside the loop (via a shortcode). Am I missing something?

Comment: Is this page an archive/listing that's been placed inside a page template with a query_posts or WP_Query at the top of the template?

Comment: @TomJNowell no. It's actually the single property post, whereby I'm trying to display a "This property is sold" message if the post belongs to the "Sold" category.

Comment: Are you calling those functions inside or outside of the loop?

Comment: @TomJNowell Inside of the loop. As I mentioned above - "Both are being used inside the loop (via a shortcode). Am I missing something?"

Comment: Does it change if you pass the 3rd argument to has_term?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'in the loop, via a shortcode'. Can you show your code? Likely the 'current post' is somehow not making it through, hence Tom's suggestion above.

Answer (score 0):

[has_term()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) need third parameter to specify which post type have this term. So, your code would be

```
if ( has_term('sold', 'category', 'property')) {
  ?>
  <div class="sold_prop_note">
    <h3>This Property is sold. Take a look at our current exclusives! <a href="/properties">View Exclusives</a></h3>
  </div>
  <?php
}
```

Beside that approach, you can use following

```
global $post; 
if (    ( $post->post_type == 'property' ) 
     && has_term( 'sold', 'category' )
) { ?>
    <div class="sold_prop_note">
        <h3>This Property is sold. Take a look at our current exclusives! <a href="/properties">View Exclusives</a></h3>
      </div>
<?php }
```